# How to use NVidia Gpu simultaneously with intel HD

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus, intel-hd

My laptop has an high-end NVidia Geforce GTX 860m graphics card and the intel integrated graphics (Intel HD 4600, pretty weak)

So in my case, i have to work in ue4 (very heavy on the graphics card), while from time to time switching to the browser to watch tutorials and find answers to questions.

So is there any way to use the NVidia card for heavy tasks, while at the same time using the intel graphics for browser? Because currently videos stutter extremely, and even web forms are very hard to fill out (a lot of lag while typing)
If anybody could have a solution for this problem, i would thank him very much.

Also, my problem is not the one described here:[How to use Intel HD Graphics for regular desktop usage, while just using my NVIDIA GPU for DNN training](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530398/how-to-use-intel-hd-graphics-for-regular-desktop-usage-while-just-using-my-nvid)
because i do not want to switch between GPU's, but run them simultaneously.

Comment: There is bumblebee project for that. But it needs configuration and does not work on 15.04 well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct nvidia+intel graphics setup in 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/472928/correct-nvidiaintel-graphics-setup-in-14-04)

Comment: Also see [Is Bumblebee still relevant for Ubuntu 14.04 and up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501772/is-bumblebee-still-relevant-for-ubuntu-14-04-and-up)

Comment: Using bumblebee they will work "at once". All programs will use Intel, some will use Nvidia.

Comment: @user68186 my question was how to get them both working at once, not why bumblebee wasn't working.

Comment: @Pilot6 sorry for previous comment, i meant user68186. About you answer, i tried bumblebee, the result was that something didn't work, because my desktop started lagging and i couldn't switch to nvidia profile. (see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/450154/nvidia-331-nvidia-settings-prime-profile-switching-error)

Comment: I recommend to discuss this at ubuntuforums.org It is possible to run it, but with latest Ubuntu versions it is a bit tricky.

Comment: I have started a new thread at ubuntu forums: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2291771 .  i suppose that this question is now considered closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your query in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2291771 and the answers there, what you are asking for is not possible.

From the forum:

> From my understanding of Nvidia Optimus technology I do not think it
>   is possible. The purpose of Optimus is automatic switching between a
>   more powerful GPU for high intensity graphic tasks with likewise high
>   battery drain and a less powerful GPU for low intensity graphic tasks
>   with the benefit of less battery drain.
>
> In Linux we have yet to get an Nvidia driver that will do automatic
>   switching.
>
> I am guessing that the problems you are having with video play back
>   are nothing to do with which GPU is being used but in connection with
>   the CPU being under intensive use and needing to task switch. The
>   Nvidia GPU should handle video playback easily. If it is not then it
>   could be a case of too much going on at the same time.

On the other hand, you can try `bumblebee/optirun` as described in [Correct nvidia+intel graphics setup in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472928/correct-nvidiaintel-graphics-setup-in-14-04)

Then you can start `ue4` with `optirun` prefix, thus using the Nvidia card for it and use Intel for other processes like the browser. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
(optirun <name of the program> &)
```

The (parenthesis) and `&` will detach the process from the terminal. This will allow you to work on the terminal after launching the program.  [There are other ways of completely detaching the program from the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal).

Also see [How does bumblebee optirun actually work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392028/how-does-bumblebee-optirun-actually-work).

I don't have an Nvidia card, so I have not tried it.

Hope this helps

Comment: do you perhaps know how to run the desktop with the nvidia card?

Comment: Apparently this can be set in the BIOS in some computers. If yours don't have that option, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/511440/nvidia-optimus-how-to-disable-onboard-intel-gpu-so-that-nvidia-drivers-work-o

Comment: Sorry, i formulated the question in my last comment the wrong way.  I am running docky (http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki) which lags when using the intel gpu on it. Since docky always starts automatically, i would just have to edit the command that runs when i start the computer and ad `optirun` to it. Am i correct? And if yes, where would such commands be located?

Comment: Ok, it worked. video is running smooth on browser using intel hd while ue4 is using nvidia gpu. However in order to start programs i first have to open terminal and type `optirun bash` and then `optirun nameofprogram`. please dit your answer to include this. (see https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/42)

Comment: Added a way to detach the terminal from optirun in the answer.